# Magento product file attribute

Tags: file, magento, attributes

I have created an attribute set with some attribute in Magento. I need a file browse button in that product attribute set,and I need to show the file in the front end.Is it possible with attributes?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no attribute type to upload file in magento. But if you are talking a file as if it is an image then there is an attribute type called **Media Image**.

Hope this will help.